# Calculator class, parsing and processing multiple operations in single input line

Tags: java, parsing, operator-precedence

I'm working on a calculator class to better understand Java. Below is a skeleton of my code to give you an idea. For now, it can only handle simple commands, such as `2+2`, `2/2`, `2^2`, etc.

Can anyone provide guidance or examples on how to proceed from here?

1. How can I adjust my parser to understand more complicated commands, such as `(2 + (2 * 2^2)) / 2`? Also, how can I adjust my methods to accept any number of arguments? I use an array to store my values and operators. Perhaps I could use an ArrayList so it can handle whatever number of elements/arguments?
2. How can I establish general guidelines and order of operations (PEMDAS) to guide my program in its calculations?

Thanks for the help!

```
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public abstract class Calc 
    {
        private static double num1, num2;

        public static void start()
        {
            System.out.println("Calculator. Type \"exit\" to quit.");
            System.out.print("> ");

            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);       
            String entry = scan.nextLine();

            while (! (entry.equals("exit")))
            {    

                String [] operands = entry.replaceAll("\\s+", "").split("[\\+\\-\\/\\*\\%\\^]");        
                String operator = entry.replaceAll("(\\s+|\\d+|\\.)", "");

                Double [] numbers = new Double[operands.length];
                for (int i = 0; i < operands.length; i++)
                {
                    numbers[i] = new Double(operands[i]);
                }

                num1 = numbers[0];
                num2 = numbers[1];

                double result = 0;

                switch (operator)
                {
                    case "+":
                        result = Calc.add(num1, num2);
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        ...
                    case "*":
                        ...
                    case "/":
                        ...
                    case "^":
                        ...
                    case "%":
                       ...
                    default:
                        System.out.println("Not valid.");
                }

                System.out.println(result);
                System.out.print("> ");
                entry = scan.nextLine();
            }
        }

        public static double add(double num1, double num2)
        {
            double sum = num1 + num2;
            return sum;
        }

        public static double subtract(double num1, double num2)
        {
            ...
        }

        public static double multiply(double num1, double num2)
        {
            ...
        }

        public static double divide(double num1, double num2)
        {
            ...
        }

        public static double exponentiate(double num1, double num2)
        {
            ...
        }

        public static double modulus(double num1, double num2)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
```

Comment: Review parse mathematical expression algorithms like [shunting yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) and then evaluate the expression.

Comment: Not what you asked - but you might want to use `BigDecimal` instead of `double / Double`.  Otherwise, you might get a nasty surprise when you work out `0.1 + 0.2`.

Comment: I would do it by using a stack. Then `push` all left parenthesis until I find a right parenthesis and then I can start popping.

Comment: @DavidWallace Good idea. I haven't used BigDecimal before but I'm aware of its uses. Do you know how I can adjust my methods (add(), subtract(), exponentiate(), etc) to accept BigDecimal arguments and return a BigDecimal object?

Comment: @DavidWallace I figured it out. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score -1):

A very simple way to do it would be to run  through it multiple times.
Say you have the following expression

`2 + 2 * 2^2 / 2`

First run through and do the exponentials. You are left with

`2 + 2 * 4 / 2`

Then run through and to multiplication/division

`2 + 4`

Then Addition/Subtraction

`6`

Ta-Da!

You would want to store the expression as a String and parse through for the operator you are looking for. then get the adjacent numbers and shrink the whole thing into one number. Parentheses are a little harder but can be accomplished in mostly the same way with recursion. Just do the above method on every level of parentheses.

Comment: This problem was solved in 1960 in a single pass, *O(N).* There is no need at this late date to start introducing less efficient alternatives. See @LuiggiMendoza's comment above,